# Const tag inconsistency (?)

Tags: c++

Why is this legal

```
int i=4;
const int *l=&i;
cout<<*l;
i=6;
cout<<*l;
```

(shows 46)

But this isn't?

```
int i=4;
const int *l=&i;
*l=4;
```

(those 2 being the same, conceptually, from my understanding)

The way I understand those 2 examples is that both shouldn't be allowed, but the former works. Why is this?

Comment: `*l=4;` tries to modify a "const" object where `i=6;` does not.  `const` doesn't mean the value can't change, it means you are not allowed to change it yourself.

Comment: In the first example, you are changing `i`. `i` is not `const`, so that's valid. In the second example, you define `l` to be a pointer to a constant integer. All that means is you can't change the value `l` points to _through_ `l`, which you are trying to do.

Comment: Why wouldnt the first one be legal?

Answer (score 5):

A pointer-to-const only promises that the pointee won't be changed *using this pointer*, not in general.

And even this promise can be broken without UB with `const_cast`, if the pointee object isn't truly `const`.

Comment: "if the pointee object isn't truly const" is an important point, because if the pointee *is* const, then such a `const_cast` would be UB (as you well know).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yep. Or rather, the modification would UB. I believe the cast itself is fine regardless.

Comment: Agreed, the cast itself would be legal, but modifying the target wouldn't be.

Answer (score 5):

You're allowed to change `i`, since it's not `const`.

When I do `i = 6;`, I'm assigning a value to an `int`, which is legal.

When I do `*l = 4;`, I'm assigning a value to something as though it was declared a `const int`, which is not legal.

All `const int* l;` means is that `l` is not allowed to change the value of the `int` it points to; it doesn't mean no-one is allowed to.

Comment: Maybe change the second one to *I'm assigning a value `i` as if it was declared as const, which is not legal.*?